# Porque no puedo correr sass con npm?

Tags: css, nodejs, npm, sass

Soy nuevo con Sass y no tuve ningún problema con la instalación y la configuración que realicé en el archivo `package.json` de está manera:

```
    {
  "name": "sass_sandbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
  }
}
```

hasta que ejecute en la terminal `npm run sass` y tuve un error:

```
"CSS" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Ignacio Tapia\Desktop\BACK-UP\node-sass\bin\node-sass'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola jose  te recomiendo que mires este tutorial , para correr sass con npm y compilarlo por terminal [instalacion sass y primeros pasos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHp2nr2kErs&t=984s)